# Update g++ reached from NetBeans under OS X

Tags: c++, netbeans

I am trying to build a `C++` project in `NetBeans 8.2` under OS X with the `C++14` standard. However, I am always getting the error while trying to build:

```
g++    -c -g -std=c++14 -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/test.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/test.o test.cpp
error: invalid value 'c++14' in '-std=c++14'
make[2]: *** [build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/test.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 570ms)
```

Nevertheless, I can run the same command from the terminal without any problems. My version of `g++` is 7.0.0, and so the `C++14` standard is fully supported.

Therefore, it seems like `NetBeans` tries to run some older version of `g++`, which was probably supplied with the system but now is replaced with a new one. To this I have two questions:

1. How can it be possible that default versions in the terminal and `NetBeans` are different?
2. How can I configure `NetBeans` to work with the terminal default version?

**EDIT:**

In the terminal `which g++` yields `/opt/local/bin/g++`. The same is in the field `Preferences` -> `C/C++` -> `C++ compiler`. Adding the `--version` argument in  `NetBeans` yields `Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)`, which is definitely different from the console version. So, I still do not understand: **why calling `g++` under the same path resolves to different versions in NetBeans and the terminal?**

Comment: Have you tried `-std=gnu++14`? After gcc 4.9.3 some distributions of it require this command. You can also try to add --version command in NetBeans to check if you really have 2 different compiler versions installed

Comment: You can see the toolchain, used by NetBeans, in `Tools -> Options -> C++` popup window, and make updates there as well